# Conda environment not showing up in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed miniconda on Windows 10 and created an environment (I followed this guide: https://www.notion.so/shashankkalanithi/Setting-Up-Conda-Environment-ba83f7f019ea44b9af37588eed419eb9). However when I open the VS Code I don't see that environment python interpeter on kernel list. There is only one interpreter on the list: ~\Miniconda3\python.exe

How can I fix this?

Comment: Manually set the python interpreter: [VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments)

Comment: Is there not a canonical answer for this? I feel like I see this asked all the time, but I don't use VSC, so it's not something I keep tabs on. Someone please ping me if you have a duplicate to recommend.

Answer (score 27):

in vscode press `ctrl+shift+p` and type `python:Select Interpreter` you should see all the environment there. If it does not appear create a `.py` file and try again. also you can press the reload icon on the search bar where you typed python:select interpreter.

Comment: That's my issue. I don't see the environment after selecting python:Select Interpreter. I doesn't appear after I create .py file either.

Comment: I had the same issue @TityBoi, all my conda envs were showing up, just one did not. Restarting VSCode multiple times did the trick at some point though.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+p` (`cmd+shift+p` on Mac) and `python:Select Interpreter` solved my issue! Here I could enter a file path to my desired kernel, whereas I could not enter a file path if I clicked on the usual list of kernels in the top-right.

Comment: I can see my new interpreter after  cmd+shift+p, but clicking this new interpreter, it is not showing as my current interpreter on the top right status bar. How to fix this?@se7en

Comment: Even if I chooce my env in python:Select Interpreter, it does not activate

Comment: @TAUILAbdElilah you can activate your conda environment and type `which python` this will print the path your environment. copy the path and paste it in the python:Select Interpreter. This should solve it

Comment: I was using VSCode in SSH remote mode. I solved this issue by disconnecting, quitting VSCode, then restarting VSCode and reconnecting.

Comment: Pressing the reload icon has helped using VS Code via SSH connection.

Answer (score 13):

You can try to follow methods from
[vscode - Create a conda environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment)

> Additional notes:
> ...To ensure the environment is set up well from a shell perspective, one
> option is to use an **Anaconda prompt with the activated environment** to
> launch VS Code using the **code .** command. At that point you just need
> to select the interpreter using the Command Palette or by clicking on
> the status bar.

Comment: This did update my conda env list. Though after I opend code by clicking icon, it was back to the problematic state. The envs are corretly shown in `python venv manager` extension, but not in `select interpreter` menu. To be exact, just after they show up, they are gone. I could just see a blink of them

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to use the new environment as a Jupyter kernel and had to install the `jupyter` package for it to show up in the kernel selection of VSCode. You can install it by running `conda install jupyter`.

Comment: doesn't work for me, my VSC still doesn't show all the kernels.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I built the environment from within vscode terminal with `conda create --name blah python=3.11`, but it still didn't appear. But if you activate environment and install jupyter as above, problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

You may check and set up the Conda path. It seems VS code has some problem to find the envs installed. You can go to Setting and search "Conda". Find "Python: Conda Path", and add the path of executable `conda`. Good luck!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33932762)

Comment: Actually, I faced the same problem as the asker, and I solved it by the answer I have given. In my case, the conda environments did not show up simply because VS code does not find `conda`. I explicitly set up the path and it worked.

Comment: This absolutely solves the root problem.  Every other answer is a work-around.

Comment: For me this answer was also the one that fixed the issue. Note: some other tools require only the path to the the directory that contains a lib/executable, but in this case VSCode really demands a path that includes the executable itself, so `path/to/conda.exe`, not just `path/to`. Thought i'd mention it here, since it cost me an additional two hours figuring that out ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to create an environment with python in it otherwise it won't recognize it. Create an environment like this first

```
conda create --name tf26 python==3.10
```

Use your preferred name and python version here thereafter restart VS Code. You will definitely see your env.

Note:
You can delete any unused env if want like this

```
conda env remove --name <env_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the problem.
This [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3732#issuecomment-447985108) says that you need to create the conda environment passing the python argument:

```
conda create -n your_env_name python=3.7
```

Doing this the environment appears in the `Select interpreter to start Jupyter server` options.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. It's also stated here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment. You need to specifiy the interpreter, otherwise the environment won't appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The extension automatically looks for interpreters in the [following locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments):

> Conda environments that contain a Python interpreter. VS Code does not
> show conda environments that don't contain an interpreter.

After you create a conda environment, you need to activate it and install some packages in order to get the python interpreter. And remember to reload the VSCode. If it still does not exist, you can try to choose `Enter interpreter path`, to point the path manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your project `.vscode/settings.json` file, just replace the old `python.pythonPath` setting with the new one (or add if non-existing) `python.defaultInterpreterPath` and it will work. The value for the setting is the path to the *venv* you're using in your project.

Afterward, `Ctrl+Shift+P` via `Python: Select Interpreter` will allow you to choose a different interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After I opened Anaconda Prompt as Administrator and created the environment, I saw it in VS code

> Open “Anaconda Prompt” from the Windows start button as
> “Administrator.”

Answer (score 0):

I added anaconda scripts(`C:\Users\yesyou\Anaconda3\Scripts`) to the user environment variable [PATH](https://superuser.com/a/989665) and did `conda init cmd.exe` on my default command prompt. Once I was able to activate conda environment on my default shell of vscode  (command prompt in my case), `Select interpereter` drop-down menu started showing python interpreters inside conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. although I have conda env created and activated, the python interpreter selector does not show the target env I want;

I removed all the unused envs, and the one I want shows up in the selection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the environments if you created your environment after you launched VSCode. You can do this simply by restarting your vscode or as suggested, `ctrl+shift+p` on win or `cmd+shit+p` on mac.

Answer (score -1):

I have an environment with python installed but it still don't show up often in my VS Code.
The only solution that has worked for me every time is restarting VSC and everything works fine.

Comment: Restarting everytime couldn't be an answer !

Comment: Restarting everytime couldn't be the possible answer.

Answer (score -5):

The reason why vscode doesn't show the environment is that it doesn't have a python interpreter in it because of inheriting or something.

The solution is also simple. Just manually install python in that environment.

```
conda install python
```